# Trying to display sweet alert javascript popup message in php script but cannot write the condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display a popup message from a html form but the message not appear and I dont know how to make condition if textfields empty warning message appear, if filled a confirm message appear.

```
<button class="Edit-Button" type="submit" onclick="ConfirmMessafe()" name="submit" value="تعديل" onclick="location.href = '#';"> تعديل <img src="./../image/editAdmin.png" style=" width: 18px; height: 18px; left: 57%; top: 643px;"></button>
    
    <script>
        var ConfirmMessage=""
    window.addEventListener('load',function ConfirmMessafe(){
        swal({
            position: 'top-end',
  title: "Data Updated Successfully",
  text:"       ",
  
  icon: "success",
  
  timer: 3500,
 button: false,
});
});
</script>
```

There is php script the same functionality but I want to style it.

```
$sql = "UPDATE admin SET A_FirstName = '$A_FirstName', A_LastName='$A_LastName',  A_Email='$A_Email',  A_PhoneNum='$A_PhoneNum' WHERE AdminID='{$_SESSION['AdminID']}'";
if ($conn->query($sql)) {

echo "<script> alert('Data Updated Successfully! '); </script>";
header("Location:settingsAdmin.php");
}else{
echo $conn->error;
}

}
?>
```

Expecting a stylish pop up message in php code from the form.

Comment: 1. NEVER name anything submit. 2. Use the form submit event instead of the submit button click event